# Eloquent won't return row where('foo', '!=', 'bar') if foo is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this query in Laravel 5.7:

```
users = User::where('role', 'sales')
            ->where('tasks', '!=', 'lead')
            ->orderBy('last_name')
            ->get();
```

I expected this query to get all users that have the *sales* role, unless they are marked as *lead* in the `tasks` column (which may be `NULL`). But now I had to realize that in my app, whenever `tasks` is `NULL`, the user won't be part of the collection.

Is this usual behaviour? If so, how should I approach this problem? If not, what might cause it?

Comment: //...
    ->where(function($q)  {
                    $q->where('tasks', '!=', 'lead')
                     ->orWhereNull('tasks');
                });
    //...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` in tricky in SQL: nothing is equal to `null`, and nothing is different than `null` (even `null` itself). So basically, condition `null != 'foo'` is false.

You need to explictly chek for nullness. In pure SQL, that would look like:

```
where tasks is null or tasks != lead
```

In Lavarel, this can be done with an advanced `where` clause:

```
->where(function ($query) { $query->where('tasks', '!=', 'lead')->orWhereNull('task'); } )
```